# Limit of a function containing $\Psi(x)$

Tags: limits, taylor-expansion, special-functions

The taylor series expansion of the function 
$$f(x)=\ln(1+x)$$ around zero
is:
$$f(x)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^{(k+1)}}{k}x^k$$
Putting $x=1$ we have the alternating series:
$f(1)=1-\dfrac{1}{2}+\dfrac{1}{3}-\dfrac{1}{4}+...=\ln(2)$
The partial sum:
$$S(N)=\sum_{k=1}^N\dfrac{(-1)^{(k+1)}}{k}$$
gives the result:
$$S(N)=\ln(2)-\dfrac{1}{2}(-1)^N\left(\Psi\left(\dfrac{1}{2}N+1\right)-\Psi\left(\dfrac{1}{2}N+\dfrac{1}{2}\right)\right)$$
where $\Psi$ is the [digamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function). So we have:
$\displaystyle\lim_{N=+\infty}S(N)=\ln(2)$
which means:
$$\displaystyle\lim_{N=+\infty}\left[-\dfrac{1}{2}(-1)^N\left(\Psi\left(\dfrac{1}{2}N+1\right)-\Psi\left(\dfrac{1}{2}N+\dfrac{1}{2}\right)\right)\right]=0$$
How is it possible to prove the last limit? Thanks.

Comment: The [integral representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function#Integral_representations) of the digamma function yields $$\psi(s+\tfrac12)-\psi(s)=\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{-st}-e^{-(s+1/2)t}}{1-e^{-t}}dt=\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-st}}{1+e^{-t/2}}dt\leqslant\int_0^\infty e^{-st}dt=\frac1s.$$ More quantitatively, $$\lim_{s\to\infty}s\,(\psi(s+a)-\psi(s))=\frac1a.$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have the identity:
$$ \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{1}{(n+a)(n+b)}=\frac{\psi(a)-\psi(b)}{a-b}\tag{1} $$
hence by taking $a=\frac{N}{2}+1$ and $b=\frac{N}{2}+\frac{1}{2}$ it follows that:
$$ \psi\left(\frac{N}{2}+1\right)-\psi\left(\frac{N}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\right)=2\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{1}{(2n+N+2)(2n+N+1)}\tag{2}$$
but $\sum_{m\geq 0}\frac{1}{(2m+1)(2m+2)}$ is trivially converging, so the limit of $(2)$ as $N\to +\infty$ is simply zero.